# Fast algorithm for incremental randomized SVD

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I have a list of covariance matrices $\{\Sigma_i\}$. I want to be able to take the (randomized for performance) SVD of the average of different (incremental) subsets of this list in order to perform a rolling fit. Is there an incremental or a distributed way to do this? Would it be useful to know the randomized SVD of each of the individual $\Sigma_i$?

Comment: Would a [streaming randomized SVD algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08651) help for your application?